# Does God really care about us?

Tags: scripture, vishnu, shiva, karma

In general just wondering about it

Comment: Your question is asking about God caring about us. At the same time, it is asking why muslims are punished and about Karma. Both are unrelated questions. Questions about muslim rulers getting punished is not the scope of our site.

Comment: I am just giving an example of atrocities committed on us and why is that out of scope of this site as it is related to laws of karma.

Answer (score 7):

Yes, definitely, God really cares for us. It is said in the Bhagavad Gita.

> ananyāś cintayanto māḿ ye janāḥ paryupāsate  |
>   teṣāḿ nityābhiyuktānāḿ yoga-kṣemaḿ vahāmy aham ||9.22||
>
> But those who always worship Me with exclusive devotion, meditating on My transcendental form—to them I carry what they lack, and I preserve what they have.

He declared that he will care about the people who worships him.

Now, the question why Muslim invaders not punished for their massacres can't be answered by facts because we don't know what happened to them in their personal life after they did these invasions and massacres is not well documented. But they will be served their Karma. But we don't know when and how.

Comment: also don't know what they will become in their next lives, nor what the Hindus were in previous lives. It's like trying to understand an incident which happened today without considering any incident that happened before today.. like a blind man trying to run an obstacle course.

Comment: Are we allowed them to give them their karma?

Comment: I don't understand what you are saying. They will get the results of what they did. As @ram said in their comment, we can't judge such incidents. That's the reason I said a part of the question is Primarily opinion based.

Comment: are we allowed to deal with them as they dealt with us ?

Comment: @HVC Karma will take care of everything. As I said in the answer, they will be served their Karma. Conquerors are already dead. What will you do to them now? Did they deal with _you_ in that way you are speaking of? Some wise man said "Eye for an eye will make whole world blind".

Comment: they are dead but those who follow their religion are not.Our pacifism will be our demise we are not supposed to just let them kill us there are 1.5 billion of them we can get our revenge from them

Comment: @HVC There is no revenge things etc., all these are useless things. These people are not responsible for what people 1000 ago did. If you comment that you want to take revenge etc., this is not the right place to post all that things. Bye.

Answer (score 2):

God does not actively run the universe. It is primordial Nature, God’s shakti (power) which does everything.

> Resorting to Prakrti, Nature, which is My own Power, I send forth
>   again and again this multitude of beings that are without any freedom,
>   owing to Nature's sway over them.

Gita 9.8

> These activities do not in any way bind Me, **because I remain detached**
>   like one unconcerned in their midst.

Gita 9.9

> Under My direction and control, Nature brings out this mighty universe
>   of living and non-living beings. Thus does the wheel of this world
>   revolve.

Gita 9.10

God remains normally as a spectator. God only helps those who do spiritual practice (Gita 9.22). Others will have to live according to their karma.

Comment: so, according to you all those hindus killed by muslims were not doing spirtual practice ?

Comment: It is extremely dangerous to live in this world. Millions of people have died because some lunatic like Hitler or Pol Pot decided that they should die. What does that tell us? It tells us that God does not interfere in the world. Only the very few people who engage themselves in contemplation and worship of God will be helped by God according to Gita 9.22, i.e. God will take responsibility of only those few people who have attained some chittasuddhi (purity of mind).